# How can I have an image in the background of 4 div elements with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have an image with height of 45px and width of (45*4)px as background of 4 div elements. All of these div elements are squares of 45px. My idea was to give each div-background the i-esime quarter part of the image. I'm trying to get the desired effect using background-position of the div elements as it shows on the code. Unfortunately the result shows the 4 parts of the image in a random order and not in sequential order.
Here's the code:

````
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script>

            function begin(){

                var caselle = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

                for (i=0; i<4; i++){
                    caselle[i].style.display="inline-block";
                    caselle[i].style.height="45px";
                    caselle[i].style.width="45px";
                    caselle[i].textContent=" ";
                    caselle[i].style.backgroundImage="url(corazzata.jpg)";
                    caselle[i].style.backgroundSize="180px 45px";
                    caselle[i].style.backgroundPosition=(i*45)+"px 45px";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="begin()">
        <div id="1"></div>
        <div id="2"></div>
        <div id="3"></div>
        <div id="4"></div>
        <div id="5"></div>
        <img id="barca1" src="corazzata.jpg">
    </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Have you tried setting the image as background for a parent div and having those divs inside with no background?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the image as background for a parent div and having those divs inside with no background?

Here is an example
https://jsfiddle.net/mr_bobz/6zyw3j2d/

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">       
    </head>
    <body >
      <div style="background-color: yellow; background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/colored-powder-explosion-on-black-background-picture-id1140180560?k=20&m=1140180560&s=612x612&w=0&h=X_400OQDFQGqccORnKt2PHYvTZ3dBLeEnCH_hRiUQrY=');  height: 250px; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        <div style='height: 50px; color: white' id="1">DIV 1</div>
        <div style='height: 50px; color: white' id="2">DIV 2</div>
        <div style='height: 50px; color: white' id="3">DIV 3</div>
        <div style='height: 50px; color: white' id="4">DIV 4</div>
        <div style='height: 50px; color: white' id="5">DIV 5</div>
      </div>       
    </body>
</html>
```